# DateTimeField default fills in server restart time, not the actual object creation time

Tags: django, datetime

I'm fixing a bug in a Django 1.5 project.  There's model with a DateTimeField, but it's getting the wrong date time:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now())
```

The database indeed receives a UTC timestamp since USE_TZ=True, but it appears to be the fixed at the server restart time, not the actual event time:

```
select id,date from activity;
 id  |             date              
-----+-------------------------------
 447 | 2014-02-12 15:16:01.886809-08
 448 | 2014-02-12 15:16:01.886809-08
 446 | 2014-02-04 15:16:41.828191-08
```

Documentation is at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield

Answer (score 0):

The best modern solution is to use **auto_now_add** as in:

```
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

But why did the **default** approach fail? The call django.utils.timezone.now() is evaluated at server restart time (on common server setups).  To get the desired behavior you can pass the function itself:

```
date = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
```

The **default** takes either a value or a callable, as documented at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default

Comment: See also http://david.feinzeig.com/blog/2011/12/06/how-to-properly-set-a-default-value-for-a-datetimefield-in-django/